# localizable.strings - translate strings from code

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

is there a possibility to set cocoa app, so it will translate `NSString` (placed in code) after launching without need of using `NSLocalizedString` ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. And you probably wouldn't want this anyway, as not every string should be localizable. Some of your strings may contain display text and hence need to be localizable through `NSLocalizedString`, and on the other hand some other of your strings may affect your logic, such as strings that define the name of a resource (e.g. the string you pass to `loadNibNamed` or the name of an image or audio file to load). These are really meant to be hardcoded and translating them would break your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, but you could create a simple macro to cut down on typing:

```
#define TRANS(s)    NSLocalizedString(s, nil)
```

Comment: But if you do this you won't be able to use the genstrings utility (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html) to automatically create your base language `.strings` file, as this utility scans your source files looking for occurrences of NSLocalizedStrings.